# Haskell generic data structure

Tags: haskell

I want to create a type to store some generic information, as for me, this type is 
Molecule, where i store chemical graph and molecular properties.

```
data Molecule = Molecule {
     name :: Maybe String,
     graph :: Gr Atom Bond,
     property :: Maybe [Property] -- that's a question
} deriving(Show)
```

Properties I want to represent as tuple

```
type Property a = (String,a)
```

because a property may have any type: Float, Int, String e.t.c.

---

The question is how to form Molecule data structure, so I will be able to collect any numbers of any types of properties in Molecule. If I do

```
data Molecule a = Molecule {
     name :: Maybe String,
     graph :: Gr Atom Bond,
     property :: Maybe [Property a]
} deriving(Show)
```

I have to diretly assign one type when I create a molecule.

Comment: The question here is (always) like this: what do you want to *do* with a property? Suppose you can put any type in there. Now you have a list of anything. What you usually do with such lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know in advance the set of properties a molecule might have, you could define a sum type:

```
data Property = Mass Float | CatalogNum Int | Comment String
```

If you want this type to be extensible, you could use Data.Dynamic as another answer suggests. For instance:

```
data Molecule = Molecule { name :: Maybe String,
                           graph :: Gr Atom Bond,
                           property :: [(String,Dynamic)]
                         } deriving (Show)

mass :: Molecule -> Maybe Float
mass m = case lookup "mass" (property m) of
           Nothing -> Nothing
           Just  i -> fromDynamic i
```

You could also get rid of the "stringly-typed" `(String,a)` pairs, say:

```
-- in Molecule: 
--   property :: [Dynamic]

data Mass = Mass Float

mass :: Molecule -> Maybe Mass
mass m = ...
```

Neither of these attempts gives much type safety over just parsing out of `(String,String)` pairs since there is no way to enforce the invariant that the user creates well-formed properties (short of wrapping properties in a new type and hiding the constructors in another module, which again breaks extensibility).

What you might want are Ocaml-style polymorphic variants. You could look at [Vinyl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vinyl/latest/doc/html/Data-Vinyl-Lens.html), which provides type-safe extensible records.

As an aside, you might want to get rid of the `Maybe` wrapper around the list of properties, since the empty list already encodes the case of no properties.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Data.Dynamic](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html) for a psudo-dynamic typing solution.